# Kubernetes: maximum pod lifetime

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I use Kubernetes 1.6 and Docker to deploy instances/pods of a microservice.

I have a service that needs to regularly pull continuously updated data from an external repository. This update can be triggered manually on runtime, but the service is unusable during that time. Furthermore, the up-to-date data is always retrieved on startup, so that the freshly started service instance has the most recent external data.

Therefore, I would like to automatically create a fresh pod every hour (or some other frequency), and then kill the old pod.

Conceptually, it seems like I should just configure a maximum lifetime per pod in the deployment, so that Kubernetes starts a new instance/pod and kills the old one if the maximum lifetime has expired, while making sure that there is always at least on pod running.
However, [Kubernetes does not seem to provide a maximum pod lifetime](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/829).

Also, due to the data update during startup, starting the pod takes 1-2 minutes before it gets ready.

Comment: You could store that data in a pv and then schedule a cron job to run periodically to update the data store?

Comment: @user2983542 that sounds like the clean approach, but unfortunately I don't have direct access to that external data, so there is no other way than pulling it regularly.

Comment: How big is the data?

Comment: @TarunLalwani it varies, somewhere between 500MB and 10GB.

Comment: And the major time is spent downloading the file during boot? Rest program startup time is fast?

Comment: @TarunLalwani extracting and loading the data might take a little while, I haven't measured. But I guess the download is by far the most time-consuming part. What are you aiming for, I'm getting curious!

Comment: @Carsten, posted a comment, but as a answer to make sure it is readable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This meant to be as a comment but might become an answer. I am posting it as an answer so that the approach is easy to read.

So I have possible approach that might work for you. You run a global download pod which will download the files into specific folder. Let's assume download happens every 1 hour. So you will create a folder like `22-08-2017-20-00` and you create file called `latest`. The content of this `latest` file will be `22-08-2017-20-00`

The downloader when it is fetching a new update, will create a new folder and download the data to same. Once the data is downloaded, it will change the content of the latest folder to that name.

Now your main app pods will refer to this host volumes, read the file content and use that folder to start the data processing.

Now you should run few replicas. If you setup a cron and restart the pods they will boot fast (no data download) and pickup the latest data. You can do a rolling update by changing a fake parameter with no impact and do a rolling update.

Or you can also set your pods to fail after 1 hour. How to do that? Make sure your image has the timeout command

```
$ time timeout 2 sleep 12

real    0m2.002s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
```

Now you don't want all pods to fail at the same time, so you can generate a random number between 50min to 70min and let each pod fail at a different time and be restarted automatically by k8s

See if the approach makes any sense

Comment: Thanks, looks promising, I'll try later. Just to make sure I get the idea of the timeout command right: the `time` command is only there for demonstrating. The `2` is the value after which the pod is supposed to die (i.e. to be replaced by random value). The `12` is just 'something larger than 2' to make sure something runs longer than the desired timeout. Right?

Comment: Note that using a random delay is risky because if the random delay is too small, there might not be enough time to restart the first pod that has been killed (in the case of two pods running). The solution for this is easy, of course, it just requires a little extra care for the delay randomization.

Comment: @Carsten, so did this approach work for you as such?

Comment: I am trying to clean up the mess that made this necessary in the first place, but it works for now, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Here there is an example that could help you: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod

metadata:
  labels:
    test: liveness
  name: liveness-exec
spec:
  containers:

  - name: liveness

    args:
    - /bin/sh
    - -c
    - touch /tmp/healthy; sleep 30; rm -rf /tmp/healthy; sleep 600

    image: gcr.io/google_containers/busybox

    livenessProbe:
      exec:
        command:
        - cat
        - /tmp/healthy
      initialDelaySeconds: 5
      periodSeconds: 5
```

Using health checks you can force to have the container rescheduled after some time. I think that could suit your case.

Comment: Exploiting liveness checks looks like a good idea, but I don't see a way to make sure a new pod is started and ready before the old one gets killed.

Comment: In my opinion, it looks to me that there should be another alternative that does not imply having to pull an entire dataset (leaving the service unusable for 1-2 minutes). It is worth checking other alternatives like sidecar containers so you do not have to fully restart the service. http://blog.kubernetes.io/2015/06/the-distributed-system-toolkit-patterns.html

Comment: @Carsten when you configure a readiness probe this works automatically - the new pod is added to the service after the readiness succeeds and then the old pod is stopped.

Comment: @JavierSalmeron also, why do we need the `sleep 600` in the end?

Comment: @Carsten that's an example from the page. In this example they do not have a daemonized process, hence the sleep. In your case you would have to specify some kind of logic in a script or in the application itself.